# net/http.Request.URL.Host returns empty string

Tags: http, url, go, request

I was trying to redirect my client to https url. And I tried this:

```
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.URL.Scheme != "https" {
                http.Redirect(w, r, "https://"+r.URL.Host+r.URL.Path, 301)
                return
        }
//....
}
```

But it gave me this response:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https:///
Date: Sat, 24 Nov 2018 20:02:33 GMT
Content-Length: 44

<a href="https:///">Moved Permanently</a>.
```

The mysterious thing is `Location: https:///` this line. And I read the go doc again and found:

> ```
> // URL specifies either the URI being requested (for server
> // requests) or the URL to access (for client requests).
> //
> // For server requests the URL is parsed from the URI
> // supplied on the Request-Line as stored in RequestURI.  **For
> // most requests, fields other than Path and RawQuery will be
> // empty. (See RFC 7230, Section 5.3)**
> //
> // For client requests, the URL's Host specifies the server to
> // connect to, while the Request's Host field optionally
> // specifies the Host header value to send in the HTTP
> // request.
> URL *url.URL
> ```

Then I've understood that why it's returning and empty string for `r.URL.Host`.

I have also tried `r.Header.Get("Host")` and then `r.Header.Get("Origin")`. It also gave me an empty string.

Any other way to get the host name?

Comment: **For
// most requests, fields other than Path and RawQuery will be
// empty. (See RFC 7230, Section 5.3)** this line from godoc describes well that why the `r.URL.Host` is empty. But is there any other way to get a non empty host name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using r.Host?

The docs say:

```
// For server requests Host specifies the host on which the URL
// is sought. Per RFC 7230, section 5.4, this is either the value
// of the "Host" header or the host name given in the URL itself.
```

So Maybe try that?

```
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Scheme != "https" {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "https://"+r.Host+r.URL.Path, 301)
            return
    }
//....
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, and accepted as answer for answering with example.

Comment: For non-proxy requests, r.URL.Scheme is always the empty string. You can reduce the body of the handler to the `http.Redirect` call.

Answer (score 2):

From `go doc http.request`:

```
type Request struct {
        ...
        // For incoming requests, the Host header is promoted to the
        // Request.Host field and removed from the Header map.
       ...
        Header Header
       ...
        // For server requests Host specifies the host on which the
        // URL is sought. Per RFC 2616, this is either the value of
        // the "Host" header or the host name given in the URL itself.
        ...
        Host string
```

Thus, use `r.Host` not `r.Header.Get("Host")`